# Connection remains empty in Winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Trying to link the project(Winform) with database. I have added the database to the resources of project. Now I'm trying to set up a connection with the database, but I am having problem in setting the connection. I have put all the connection code in a class    (named connect_class). Following is the code of what I have tried.

```
Form.cs:

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ob_connect = new connect_class();

        ob_connect.str_con = Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString;
        ob_connect.sql_string = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;

        d_s = ob_connect.MyDataSet();
        max_rows = d_s.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        navigate_records();
    }
    catch(Exception er)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
    }
}
```

connect_class:

```
class connect_class
{
    public string sql_string;
    public string str_con;
    public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter d_a;
    public System.Data.DataSet d_s;
    public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;


    public connect_class()
    {
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(str_con);
        d_a = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);
        d_s = new System.Data.DataSet();
    }

    public System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        con.Open();               // <-- when execution reach at this point a 
        d_a.Fill(d_s);            //     messageBox show "Incorrect Syntax near keyword 'Table'"
        con.Close();
        return d_s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the values of these defaults definitely what you intend to be using? For the connection and sql strings?

Comment: When I debug the code, I find the values to be correct. The problem comes in the MyDataSet() method in the very first line con.Open();

Comment: When the execution reach this line, a messageBox shows "Incoorect Syntax near the keyword 'Table'".

Comment: Can you post the sql you're trying to execute? The value of sql_string?

Comment: @DavieBrown.Got it done. There was a problem with the database I was creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the connection string after the initialization of the class. But in the initialization you build your SqlConnection using the connection string. At that point in time the connection string is still blank, the same happens for your sql_string. You use it before having it initialized

You could change your class forcing your clients to pass the connection string and the sql_string in the constructor

```
class connect_class
{
    public string sql_string;
    public string str_con;
    public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter d_a;
    public System.Data.DataSet d_s;
    public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;


    public connect_class(string connectionString, string sql_command)
    {
        this.str_con = connectionString;
        this.sql_string = sql_command;
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(str_con);
        d_a = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);
        d_s = new System.Data.DataSet();
    }
    .....
}
```

However, I would prefer to create the objects (connection, adapter and dataset) just when you need to use them and avoid dangerous global variables for disposable objects

```
class connect_class
{
    public string sql_string;
    public string str_con;
    // With the code below, these are no more needed. 
    // Keep globalse just the connectionstring and the sql string to execute        
    // public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter d_a;
    // public System.Data.DataSet d_s;
    // public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;


    public connect_class()
    {
        // Nothing needed here,
        // Of course before calling MyDataSet you need to set the public properties
        // for the connection string and sql command text.
    }

    public System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(this.str_con))
        using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, cn))
        {
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also tried a method. In the method I declared the connection, and the data_adapter and the data_set. But that way didn't worked either.

Comment: That was my mistake. Now I have modified the code but still the problem is as it is.

Comment: Do you get any error message? If yes, what is it? and what is the values used for `sql_string` and `str_con`?

Comment: I get a runtime error(I have edited the question, now it contains the error I get In MyDataSet method). sql_string = Select * from Table and  str_con = (The connection string I have modified in the Properties, to  refer to the database);

Comment: Do you have table called 'Table' in your database?

Comment: yes. Name of the table I have stored data in, is Table.

Comment: Got it done. There was a problem with the database I was creating. Thankyou for your help.